# Raising a custom event on a custom tool control

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to test something out and can't quite figure it out. I have a custom user control I've created with a SDK addon to Microsoft VS 2012. I'm not too great yet with events or delegates.

My desire is when this control is enabled (or disabled), it raises an event to start (or stop) a timer1. When this timer1 reaches a specified time, it calls a method that creates a tcp client and performs a server request.

This is my code from my user control which is hosted on a main form.

```
    public custom_cont()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        EnabledChanged += new EventHandler(OnEnabledChanged); 
    }

    int timer1Count;

     public void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1Count++;
        if (timer1Count == TickTimer) //TickTimer is a property I can control from my usercontrol hosted project.
            ProcessUpload(); // Tcp-client creation... takes cares of send and receive response
    }


    public void OnEnabledChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Enabled)
            timer1.Start();
        else
            timer1.Stop();
    }
```

On my main form, I have many custom controls of this same type contained within `controlList` which is a `List<T>`, and when I enable them:

```
foreach (var control in controlList)
        {
                control.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Nothing happens. The user control is supposed to change color based on connection status within my `ProcessUpload()`. When I call my `ProcessUpload()` directly from main form by `control.ProcessUpload()` it works. I have them linked up in the events section of my control form. How can I make the enable and timing event work so that I don't need to explicitly call the method contained within the control? Ideally they would raise based on a timing interval.

Comment: hard to tell without seeing all of your code but I guess you will get an exception from time to time ... you need to marshal your code back to the UI-thread in ProcessUpload() - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @CarstenKönig So does that mean my usercontrol runs separate from my main GUI, as in on a separate thread? It is hard to debug because I cannot put breakpoints on code that is on my usercontrol because I'm running it within another project. Right now all my variables within my tcp client method are null, so its not even getting there to begin with. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: no - but your Timer most likely does (I cannot see what kind of timer you are using here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'EnabledChanged' event will not fire when you set `Enabled = true`, unless the control is currently disabled (since there is no change). So, before adding your event handler, set it to false:

```
this.Enabled = false;
this.EnabledChanged += new EventHandler(OnEnabledChanged);
```

Comment: Thank you, this simple code addition worked. This isn't the first time you've helped me. Once I have enough rep, I'm going to upvote your answers to my questions.